# I got ValueError: Related model 'useraccount.user' cannot be resolved in my django app when I tried to migrate AbstractUser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, abstractuser

This error occurred when I try to migrate.

````
└─$ python3 manage.py migrate                                                                                                                                                                130 ⨯
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blogapp, contenttypes, forumapp, sessions, token_blacklist, useraccount
Running migrations:
  Applying useraccount.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 442, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 216, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 346, in column_sql
    field_db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1183, in db_parameters
    target_db_parameters = self.target_field.db_parameters(connection)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1060, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 747, in foreign_related_fields
    rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 734, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1103, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
  File "/home/neo/Documents/Software Development/DjangoReact/-Blog/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 712, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Related model 'useraccount.user' cannot be resolved```

models.py
```from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
````

I have attached my github repo here: https://github.com/rlopxhan21/-Blog
Code with error is in AbstarctSUerError branch. Thanks

I tried to create whole new app with just abstract user, it worked. But couldn't figure out in this app.

Comment: You need to drop database and run migration again.

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: `ValueError: Related model 'useraccount.user' cannot be resolved`, should it be `useraccount.User`, with uppercase U instead of  `useraccount.user` with lowercase u? Check your project `settings.py`

Comment: No it is useraccount.User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the command `python manage.py makemigrations` accepts the order in executing the migrations like this: `python manage.py makemigrations useraccount`

> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.

You should do the migration of your Usermodel first. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) if you are unable to drop the database. Here you will also find the text of above Quotation. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) if you can launch the entire database with all its migrations again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept it as the correct answer to your question here in stackoverflow.